# Inverse function of a function involving $o(1)$

Tags: asymptotics, inverse-function

I am bumping into a problem when trying to write the inverse function of a function involving $o(1)$.

Here we have $t= \ln n(1+o(1))$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Now I want to write $n$ as a function of $t$, but I am puzzled by not knowing the rate of convergence of $o(1)$. But maybe there’s a way that I don’t need this information?

Comment: Just to clarify, is it  $t= (1+o(1))\ln n$ or is it $t= \ln (n(1+o(1))) ?$

Comment: Yes, it is the first one you wrote here.

Comment: (Followup of the discussion which began below the answer) I don't understand what you want, Harry. Remove $o(1)$ and replace it by what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $t=(1+o(1))\ln n$, without knowing the rate of convergence of the $o(1)$, in this case you can still invert the $o(1)$ into another $o(1)$.  For all $0<\epsilon<1$, if $n$ is bigger than some $n(\epsilon)$, then by the definition of $o(1)$
$$
(1-\epsilon)\ln n\le t\le (1+\epsilon)\ln n
$$
so, exponentiating,
$$
n^{1-\epsilon}\le e^t\le n^{1+\epsilon}
$$
and then
$$
e^{t/(1+\epsilon)}\le n\le e^{t/(1-\epsilon)},
$$
so since this is true for arbitrary $\epsilon$,
$$
n=e^{t(1+o(1))}\qquad \qquad \hbox{as $n\to\infty$.}
$$
Going back to $t=(1+o(1))\log n$, this statement implies that there must be some $n_0$ such that $t\le 2\log n$ for $n\ge n_0$, so, if we assume $n\ge n_0$, then $n\ge e^{t/2}$.  In this case for each $n(\epsilon)$ there is a $t(\epsilon)$ so that if $t\ge t(\epsilon)$, also $n\ge n(\epsilon)$, so $n\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ and
$$
n=e^{t(1+o(1))}\qquad \qquad \hbox{as $t\to\infty$.}
$$

Comment: Or simply, as $t\to\infty$ i.e. $n\to\infty:$ $\ln n=\frac t{1+o(1)}=t(1+o(1)).$

Comment: @AnneBauval the first o(1) you have on the denominator is about n, and the one on the right hand side is about t or still about n? If it’s about t, why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is the same: this $o(1)$ means a function which tends to $0$ as $n$, or equivalently $t$, tends to $\infty.$

Comment: @AnneBauval it is because if t goes to infinity, n goes to infinity. Hence here by asking t goes to infinity already implies n goes to infinity, then we can do the exchange between n and t here, right?

Comment: Yes @Harry and conversely, if $n\to\infty$ then $t\to\infty$. That was the meaning of my "or equivalently".

Comment: @AnneBauval if I wanna remove o(1) here, I have to find its convergence rate right? Is there any other way to do that? Thank you